# Error message is [<<Expression Error>> divisor is zero

Tags: session, expression, workflow, informatica

Unable to find issue with data, because it worked previously now it's throwing error.

Transformation [exp_unit_allocation_Adjusted_Net_Book_Value] had an error evaluating variable column [UNIT_ADJUSTED_NBV_VAR]. Error message is [<> []: divisor is zero

Comment: Hi - what is it about the error message that you don’t understand? I’m not sure how it could be clearer about what the issue is

Comment: Its obvious that the division operation for UNIT_ADJUSTED_NBV_VAR isnt handling denominator =0 or null scenario. So, change your logic like this `UNIT_ADJUSTED_NBV_VAR = numerator/ iff(denominator =0 OR ISNULL(denominator),1,denominator)`